# Why println is being executed in this recursive piece of code?

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

In this code arrLength starts with four and then keeps being decremented until it reaches zero.
At the moment it reaches zero it should not execute what is inside the if block anymore.
But what is happening is that when it reaches zero it still executes the println line.
Not understanding how that println line is being executed since that line is inside the if block and nothing inside the if block should execute when arrLength gets to zero.
At the end it prints 5, 6, 2, 1 while in my understanding it should print nothing never executing the println line.

```
class ArrayElements{
 
    public void printElements(int arr[], int arrLength){
        if(arrLength != 0){
            arrLength--;
            printElements(arr, arrLength);
            System.out.println(arr[arrLength]);
        }
    }
}
public class Main {
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arr[] = {5,6,2,1};
        int arrLength = arr.length;
 
        ArrayElements mv = new ArrayElements();
        mv.printElements(arr, arrLength );
    }
}
```

Comment: Its because you check the arrLength before decrementing

Comment: @Jawad El Fou Still don't get it. When arrLength becomes zero it should not enter the if block.

Comment: It doesnt. Check the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to understand what is happening is to modify your printElements method like this:

```
public void printElements(int arr[], int arrLength){
    System.out.println("arrLength value is " + arrLength);
    if(arrLength != 0){
        arrLength--;
        printElements(arr, arrLength);
        System.out.println(arr[arrLength]);
    }
}
```

The output will be:

```
arrLength value is 4
arrLength value is 3
arrLength value is 2
arrLength value is 1
arrLength value is 0
5
6
2
1
```

As you can see you made 5 recursives calls but only print 4 values. The reason been the second println is not executed when arrLength is equal to 0.

This means that when arrLength is 0 you do not enter the if condition.

Comment: If I debug this new code you posted step by step after it prints "arrLength value is 0", it tests "if(arrLength != 0)". Since that is false, it does not enter the if block. But the println line is part of the if block. So it should not execute. That's why I don't understand why it is being executed.

Comment: Well it doesnt execute it but returns, and when it returns it will execute the println from the previous call. Recursives calls are stacked.

Comment: In fact you execute the recursive methods 5 times but enter the "if" only 4 times as you can see if you count the number of "printLn".

Comment: That's also the reason why it prints 5 6 2 1 and not 1 2 6 5.

Comment: I think your comment on recursive calls being stacked might explain what I'm missing here. You mean that it will run what comes after the recursive call "printElements(arr, arrLength);" all at once after the if block is false? Is that how recursive call works?

Comment: Not exactly at once. It will continue executing after the recursive call ends.

Comment: hmmm. I think I get it. Checked your answer as accepted. Thank you. If you have some additional pointers to articles where I can learn better how this stacking process works for recursive calls I appreaciate. Thanks again.